# onClickListener couses Crash with TextView

Tags: android

im trying to create a simple application with no luck
i just want to preform some action if i touches the list view
if i'm not adding the onClickListener everything is ok
java:

```
        ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewOptions);
    final ArrayList<String> optionsArray = new ArrayList<String>();



    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;


    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,optionsArray);

    for(int i =1 ; i < 3 ; i++)
    {
        optionsArray.add("1");
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    myListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    myListView.setClickable(true);
    myListView.setFocusable(true);


   OnClickListener onClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};

myListView.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
```

XML:

```
<ListView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_weight="1" 
android:id="@+id/listViewOptions" 
android:clickable="true">
</ListView>
```

Thanks

Log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  232): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead
E/AndroidRuntime(  232):    at android.widget.AdapterView.setOnClickListener(AdapterView.java:750)
E/AndroidRuntime(  232):    at com.resume.Resume.onCreate(Resume.java:52)
E/AndroidRuntime(  232):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
E/AndroidRuntime(  232):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
E/AndroidRuntime(  232):    ... 11 more
I/Process (   52): Sending signal. PID: 232 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm(  232): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
E/dalvikvm(  232): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
W/ActivityManager(   52): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
W/ActivityManager(   52): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{439114c0 com.resume/.Resume}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what causes the Exception? Look in LogCat.

Comment: Also, there's really no reason to call notifyDataSetChanged() so many times. Just populate your optionsArray first, THEN assign the ArrayAdapter.

Answer (score 4):

You need to learn to look at Logcat output... had you done so you'd see the following:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 4280): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.rjh.TestProj/org.rjh.TestProj.MainActivity}:
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead
E/AndroidRuntime( 4280):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4280):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4280):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4280):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4280):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4280):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4280):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
...
```

As it says, the problem is that you are using `OnClickListener` whereas you should be using `OnItemClickListener`.

Comment: ill try to use onItemClickListener ... i think that is the problem

Comment: myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
     long arg3) {
    
    
   }
  });